# PHP code will not execute in script tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I can put php code anywhere in my php file, but if i put the php code within the  tags it simply will not work.... What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>   
<head>
<?php
    $hello3 = 'hello3';
    echo 'hello1';
?>
    <script>
    <?php echo 'hello2'; ?>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#target").click(function(){
                alert('hello');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php echo $hello3; ?>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="target">Press Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

when I execute this page I get this displayed on my screen:

```
hello1hello3 (then the button)
```

the echo within the script tags will not execute... at all.

Comment: Make right click on your page -> view source ! It does get printed but in script tags which is javascript client side. Does this answer your question?

Comment: whoah i get something wierd, i see the hello1,2,3 but they are just scattered within the page source? What is going on? And not really, because in seperate php code block i add things to a php array, then I am trying to use php code within the js to copy the php array to a javascript array, but any php code in the js doesn't get executed...

Comment: because it's in the script tags which then client side is javascript! You also don't see your jQuery stuff right?

Comment: And what makes you think the string `"hello2"` is valid javascript and will work ?

Comment: The PHP *does* execute, as indicated by the result. Verify this yourself by *looking at the raw HTML response* (Page -> View Source ought to work) - why does that response, which is the *result of running PHP*, "not run"? Update the expectations / title / problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is the HTML equivalent of your code:

```html
<html>   
<head>
hello1
    <script>
    hello2
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#target").click(function(){
                alert('hello');
            });
        });
    </script>
    hello3
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="target">Press Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

What's wrong with your output?

Comment: right javascript doesn't recognize hello2 unless its defined.

Comment: @macas I mean, hello2 is not a function/variable/anything. What do you think this code is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this does execute. But items in the `<script>` tag are not displayed on the screen unless done so by a function or method. You just have items like `hello2;` in JavaScript. For example what would you expect so see if you had this:

```
<script>
    hello1; 
</script>
```

Well, nothing would be on the screen. You are just creating global variables, which are not defined, so what would happen? Try adding some code for example a simple alert:

```
<script>
    <?php echo 'alert("hello")'; ?>
</script>
```

When writing PHP the items you `echo` would be exactly the same as you were writing JavaScript normally. So the same rules for writing JavaScript apply. The above item would look like so after PHP executes:

```
<script>
    alert("hello")
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of your PHP, within the script element, looks like this:

```js
    hello2        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#target").click(function(){
                alert('hello');
            });
        });
```

It immediately falls over (with a reference error) because you try to use the variable `hello2` without declaring it.

Were that not the cause, it would then fall over because you try to use the variable `$` without declaring it (i.e. by including jQuery in your script).

The PHP is executing fine. You are just writing PHP that generates completely broken JavaScript.